# Google crash curse optional question solution about For loop

Tags: python

I decided to pass google curse for python beginners and stuck on this question. It is optional to solve but I'm angry about it as I understand that it is simple yet can't get the specific number.

```
def square(n):
    return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
    sum = 0
    for n in ___:
        sum += __
    return __

print(sum_squares(10)) 
# Should be 285
```

the ___ fields must be changed so the output of 10 evaluate to 285. Sorry for bothering with this simple question, but I really need to understand what is the solution for this. And again, its optional question but I want to get it))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
def square(n):
    return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
    sum = 0
    for n in range(x):
        sum += square(n)
    return sum

print(sum_squares(10)) # output will show : 285
```

Comment: OMG, square(n). why I didn`t mind  to put that instead just adding n. Thank you friend, now I'll sleep in peace.